# How can i convert this string to desired date format?

Tags: c#

How can i convert this string to desired date format
i have string like this

```
 string hourformat = dt1.ToString("H:mm"); this produce result 21:30
```

i want this to convert in this date format

```
2012-01-03 20:10:50.000, how can i achieve this
```

i used this format but producing wrong result

### wantedTime = String.Format("{0:u} : 000", DateTime.Parse(wantedTime));//2013-03-28 21:30:00Z : 000

actually i get the string in this format `"08:30 PM"`, `"10:00 AM"` that i need to convert in 24 hour format and push it to database in date tie format of 2012-01-03 20:10:50.000, please help me with this

Comment: Do not format the string yourself. If you have an ORM layer with which to access the database, it will do the conversion automatically. If you don't, use a parameterized query which will do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do that in a lot of different ways.  When you wish to convert any `DateTime` you have full customization.  A list of all the possible combinations can be [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

An example could be:

Thursday, March 28, 2013

This could easily be represented `dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy`.

As you can see you have full control, it boils down to which ever culmination you choose to use.  In your case your seeking fully numeric solution, so you would do the following:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

So as you can see it is very easy to manipulate the time.  If you are going to push it into a Database you will have to ensure the Database field supports your implementation of `DateTime`.  If it doesn't you'll have to push the `string` into your Database as a `string` into a `text field`.

But you can accomplish something similar with:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

That is a solution.  You'll have a few things to think about, but hopefully that helps you out.

Answer (score 6):

```
dt1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
```

Comment: but i my requirement is to push it in to database in date time format with the formated string.